# Sidecar doesn't support multiple instances of one NON-JVM app

Tags: spring-boot, spring-cloud, spring-cloud-netflix

I was able to register the single nodejs app instance using the netflix sidecar app successfully. Both nodejs and sidecar bridge app are running in Cloud foundry.

Result:

SAMPLE-NODEJS   n/a (1) (1) UP (1)

When i scale the nodeJS app to 3 instances, could not see the scaled instances in Eureka service registry. It still shows 1 instance.

Can some one help me to do this....

I want to register all the instances of Nodejs app with Eureka service registry with Sidecar bridge app.

Pls.. help.

Regards
Purandhar

Comment: Below is the sidecar config:

Comment: spring:
  application:
    name: Sample-NodeJS

sidecar:
  health-uri: http://<domain>/health.json

eureka:
  client:
    serviceUrl:
      defaultZone: ${vcap.services.eureka.credentials.url}/eureka/
    healthcheck:
      enabled: true
    fetch-registry: true
  instance:
    instanceId: ${vcap.application.instance_id:${spring.application.name}:${spring.application.instance_id:${random.value}}}

Comment: Do you also have 3 sidecar instances for the 3 different nodes?

Comment: No.. just one sidecar application and my nodejs app can scale dynamically based on load in Cloud foundry

Answer (score 1):

Sidecar, like the eureka java client is built to register only one application with the eureka server at a time. It is not a eureka proxy for multiple applications. I built a [proof of concept proxy](https://github.com/spencergibb/spring-cloud-netflix-eureka-lite) that will do what you want.

Answer (score 0):

This happens because it's not your node application, which is registering to eureka, but your sidecar, which still runs in one instance.

### simple solution

you scale your sidecars with your node apps. This is quite straight forward, in particular when using container based deployment. You just can craft a docker container starting both, a node instance and a sidecar.

### load balancing

you can extend your sidecar application to load balance traffic to your sidecars. Then your node apps will still be shown as a single instance, but still have load balancing to scaled node instances